# Creating a bubble sort method from scratch and run into a "<" noMethod error

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort

Making a bubble sort method from scratch and continually run into a noMethod error citing the "<" sign as the culprit.

```
array = [2, 1]

def bubble_sort(arg)
    count = 0
    while count < arg.length 
        arg.each do |n|
            if arg[n] > arg[n + 1]
                arg[n], arg[n + 1] = arg[n + 1], arg[n]
            end
            count += 1
        end
    end
    puts arg
end

bubble_sort(array)
```

Any help, beyond what I'm asking as well, will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `arg.each do |n|` - n is array element, not index. If you want index, use `each_with_index`

Comment: @sawa why do I run into that error and how do I get the code to work -- that is iterate through the array until the array is sorted from the least values to the greatest values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From first glance I can see a few problems with ur bubbles sort algo.

editing ur code I came up with this... I do not have a means of running this as of now, so I don't know if the below code would also be valid... buh there's no harm in trying rai.

```
count = 0

while count < arg.length 
    n = 0
    while n < arg.length - count
        if arg[count] > arg[n+count]
            arg[count], arg[n+count] = arg[n+count], arg[count]
        end
        n += 1
    end
    count += 1
end
puts arg
```

That should do the fix... lemme know if it doesn't work

Comment: Edited... sorry I skiped

Comment: Finally I had time to test the above and it did worked... One of the problem with ur code was using variable n as an index whereas it is an array element